# Select columns from a dataframe based on values present

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel file with many columns and rows. 
I want to select and import only some of these columns as long as they have right content (i.e. if any one of the column cells contains `CUP`)

I have the below code, but I its not working.[image: my_excel photo]

```
import pandas as pd
mystring = pd.read_excel("my_excel.xlsx", parse_cols='CUP' in col for cols in my_excel.xlsx, skiprows=[0])
mystring = data.to_string()
print(mystring)


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Output should be like this:

```
mystring = 'SHOVEL2 CUP UMBRELLA WALLET MIKE GENARAL BASKET COFFEE TEA CUP SCREENING MOVIES'
```

I have attached my excel file photo here.

Comment: Unfortunately, you must import the whole thing and then filter columns based on content. `pd.read_excel` does not provide the functionality to view content inside the excel until it is loaded. If you want to selectively load columns, you'll need to know in advance what columns you want to include.

Comment: @coldspeed I see.
Should I import every column in excel as a separate string? 
Then select strings containing `CUP` and then concatenate all selected strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned, you'll need to import your data *first*, then filter it, and then join your filtered columns.

```
df = pd.read_excel("my_excel.xlsx", skiprows=[0])
m = df.isin(['CUP']).any(axis=0)
mystring = ' '.join(df.loc[:, m].values.ravel('F'))
```

Comment: I tried the code, I got this error
`IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match`

Comment: @Nguyen Ah, I suppose the problem was the indexing. I've changed that now, so check again?

Comment: @COLDSPEED when I ran the code on bigger excel file, this error appeared
`TypeError: sequence item 1155: expected str instance, datetime.datetime found`

Comment: @Nguyen convert your data frame to str before you call join: .astype(str). Your data seems to have a datetime column in it, not sure how.

Comment: @coldspeed I tried it on other excel file. Ok I did like you said
`df = df.astype(str)`

Comment: @Nguyen did it work? If not, please open a question with a few rows of your actual data containing the columns that are giving you trouble. :)

Comment: Thanks again @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, its all good :) this sorting saves a lot of time